# join in a dataframe spark java

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

First of all, thank you for the time in reading my question.

My question is the following: In Spark with Java, i load in two dataframe the data of two csv files.

These dataframes will have the following information.

Dataframe Airport

```
Id | Name    | City
-----------------------
1  | Barajas | Madrid
```

Dataframe airport_city_state

```
City | state
----------------
Madrid | España
```

I want to join these two dataframes so that it looks like this:

dataframe result

```
Id | Name    | City   | state
--------------------------
1  | Barajas | Madrid | España
```

Where `dfairport.city = dfaiport_city_state.city`

But I can not clarify with the syntax so I can do the join correctly. A little code of how I have created the variables:

```
 // Load the csv, you have to specify that you have header and what delimiter you have
Dataset <Row> dfairport = Load.Csv (sqlContext, data_airport);
Dataset <Row> dfairport_city_state = Load.Csv (sqlContext,   data_airport_city_state);


// Change the name of the columns in the csv dataframe to match the columns in the database
// Once they match the name we can insert them
Dfairport
.withColumnRenamed ("leg_key", "id")
.withColumnRenamed ("leg_name", "name")
.withColumnRenamed ("leg_city", "city")

dfairport_city_state
.withColumnRenamed("city", "ciudad")
.withColumnRenamed("state", "estado");
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, thank you very much for your response.

I have tried both of my solutions but none of them work, I get the following error:
The method dfairport_city_state (String) is undefined for the type ETL_Airport

I can not access a specific column of the dataframe for join.

EDIT:
Already got to do the join, I put here the solution in case someone else helps;)

Thanks for everything and best regards

```
//Join de tablas en las que comparten ciudad
Dataset <Row> joined = dfairport.join(dfairport_city_state, dfairport.col("leg_city").equalTo(dfairport_city_state.col("city")));
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer - helped me fix my own issue  -I needed a way to join using Column expression like `datasetA.col("name").equalsTo(datasetB.col("first_name")`.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `join` method with column name to join two dataframes, e.g.:

```
Dataset <Row> dfairport = Load.Csv (sqlContext, data_airport);
Dataset <Row> dfairport_city_state = Load.Csv (sqlContext,   data_airport_city_state);

Dataset <Row> joined = dfairport.join(dfairport_city_state, dfairport_city_state("City"));
```

There is also an overloaded version that allows you to specify the `join` type as third argument, e.g.:

`Dataset <Row> joined = dfairport.join(dfairport_city_state, dfairport_city_state("City"), "left_outer");`

[Here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/high-performance-spark/9781491943199/ch04.html)'s more on joins.

Comment: You can not access column like this, this works in Scala not in java dfairport_city_state("City"), 
In java, you have to add 
    import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*; 
     col("City") buisnessPlus.col("City")

Comment: In recent spark versions, you can pass a third argument to join method, specifying the join type, for instance, "inner".