# Apache Spark : how to insert data in a column with empty values in dataFrame using Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have to insert values available in **DataFrame1** into one of the column with empty values with **DataFrame2**. Basically updating column in **DataFrame2**.

Both DataFrames have 2 common columns.

Is there a way to do same using Java? Or there can be different approach?

**Sample Input :**

1) File1.csv

```
BILL_ID,BILL_NBR_TYPE_CD,BILL_NBR,VERSION,PRIM_SW
0501841898,BIN     ,404154,1000,Y
0681220958,BIN     ,735332,1000,Y
5992410180,BIN     ,454680,1000,Y
6995270884,SREBIN  ,1000252750295575,1000,Y
```

Here `BILL_ID` is system id and `BILL_NBR` is external id.

2) File2.csv

```
TXN_ID,TXN_TYPE,BILL_ID,BILL_NBR_TYPE_CD,BILL_NBR
01234, ABC     ,"     ",BIN     ,404154
22365, XYZ     ,"     ",BIN     ,735332
45890, LKJ     ,"     ",BIN     ,454680
23456, MPK     ,"     ",SREBIN  ,1000252750295575
```

**Sample Output**

As shown below `BILL_ID` value should be populated in `File2.csv`

```
01234, ABC     ,501841898,BIN     ,404154
22365, XYZ     ,681220958,BIN     ,735332
45890, LKJ     ,5992410180,BIN     ,454680
23456, MPK     ,6995270884,SREBIN  ,1000252750295575
```

I have created two DataFrames and loaded both file's data into it, now I am not sure how to proceed.

**EDIT**

Basically I want clarity on below three steps:

1. how to get BILL_NBR and BILL_NBR_TYPE_CD values from File2.csv?

For this step I have written : `file2Df.select("BILL_NBR_TYPE_CD","BILL_NBR");`

2. How to get BILL_ID values from File1.csv based on the values retrieved in step1 ?
3. How to update BILL_ID values accordingly in File2.csv ?

I am new to spark and I would appreciate if someone can give pointers.

Comment: This is a simple SQL join problem. Do an inner join between `df1` and `df2` and then select column appropriately from either `df1` or `df2`

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43033835/join-in-a-dataframe-spark-java

Comment: @philantrovert Thank you for pointing out ......but can inner join be performed based on two columns? I was checking the API for same. also BILL_ID column which is empty in File2, where will that go?

Comment: @philantrovert I have tried Dataset <Row> joined = txnDf.join(accountDf,txnDf.col("BILL_NBR").equalTo(accountDf.col("BILL_NBR")).and(txnDf.col("BILL_NBR_TYPE_CD").equalTo(accountDf.col("BILL_NBR_TYPE_CD"))),"inner");  as per your suggestion but got this error : Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Found duplicate column(s) when inserting
allation and books/Output Files/Transformed23Apr.csv: `bill_nbr`, `bill_id`, `bill_nbr_type_cd`;

Answer (score 0):

You need to join two tables based on `BILL_NBR` column.

**Assumption:** There is one to one relation between `BILL_NBR` and `BILL_ID` columns.

Assuming that your dataframe names for File1.csv and File2.csv are `file1DF` and `file2DF` respectively, following should work for you:

```
Dataset<Row> file1DF = file1DF.select("BILL_ID","BILL_NBR","BILL_NBR_TYPE_CD");
Dataset<Row> file2DF = file2DF.select("TXN_ID","TXN_TYPE","BILL_NBR_TYPE_CD","BILL_NBR");
Dataset<Row> file2DF = file2DF.join(file1DF, file1DF("BILL_NBR","BILL_NBR_TYPE_CD"));
```

Note: I haven't got resources to test above code by running it. Please let me know if you face any compile time or run time error.

Comment: there is one to one relation between BILL_NBR,BILL_NBR_TYPE_CD to BILL_ID, so join should be done based on those two columns right? can you update the code?

Comment: yeah add the other column also and it should work. Have you tried that?

Comment: Updated the code. Not sure about correctness of the syntax.

Comment: do a crossJoin() and store it back on some condition

Comment: @vatsalmevada in the last line you have written file1DF("BILL_NBR","BILL_NBR_TYPE_CD") which gives compiler error as there is no such function defined, do you meant to use select there?

Comment: @Mavericks Can you please give some example?